# Edit data and save back to database

Tags: vb.net

I just need to edit one field on a datarow and save the changes back to the database. 
My database is SQL Compact 3.5

I tried many methods but change is not saved to database.  Could you give me code example please?

Please help.

```
Me.taSet.Fill(Me.Dsset.tblQuestions) 
Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(1).BeginEdit() 
Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(1).Item("ExamID") = "EDITED"
Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(1).AcceptChanges() 
taSet.Update(Dsset.tblQuestions)
```

Comment: Could you show the different methods you've tried so that we can see what's wrong with them?

Comment: Me.taSet.Fill(Me.Dsset.tblQuestions)
        Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(1).BeginEdit()
        Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(1).Item("ExamID") = "EDITED"
        Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(1).AcceptChanges()
        taSet.Update(Dsset.tblQuestions)

Comment: Could you kindly advise me any. I just need to edit coloumn 2 of row 0

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your code :

```
Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(1).AcceptChanges()
```

When you call `AcceptChanges()`, you mark that row as clean (which means this row has not been edited). That is why it does not get upodated.